# How can I install Google OR-Tools on Mac?

Tags: python, macos, macos-mojave, or-tools

Trying to install Google OR-Tools by running in the terminal:

```
python3 -m pip install -U --user ortools
```

I end up with errors:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ortools (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for ortools
```

What might I be missing?

---

*OSX 10.14.6,
Python 3.10,
pip 21.3.1,
Homebrew 3.3.2*

Comment: Had no problems when I used
```python -m pip install ortools```

Comment: @Lesnek Thx. When running `python3 -m pip install ortools` I get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

python 3.10 was released after or-tools 9.1.
Next release will contain the 3.10 wheel.

Comment: Thx. So I will just wait..

Comment: do you already know when the next or-tools release will be due?

Comment: Hopefully this month. We have some cleaning up to do.